# Why WolframAlpha gives different results?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

Any idea why WolframAlpha gives different answers when computing the indefinite integral of these functions with respect to x first or with respect to y first?

[image]

[Left](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%20%5B%28x%28x-y%29%5E2%29%20%2F%20%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5D%20%20dy%20dx) [Right](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral++%5B%28x%28x-y%29%5E2+%29%2F+%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5D+dx+dy)

[image]

[Left](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%20%28%20integral%20%28xy%20%28x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%20dy%20%29%20dx) [Right](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%28integral%20%28xy%20%28x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%20dx%29%20%20dy)

[image]

[Left](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%20%5Bd%2Fdx%20d%2Fdy%20%20%28xy%20%28x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%5D%20dy%20dx) [Right](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%20%5Bd%2Fdx%20d%2Fdy%20%20%28xy%20%28x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%5D%20dx%20dy)

This question emerge from splitting [this deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685376/can-you-always-inverse-the-order-of-integration-of-an-indefinite-integrals) into two question because I thought it was too messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that WolframAlpha produces different results because Mathematica produces different results:

```
integrand = (x*(x - y)^2)/(x^2 + y^2);
anti1 = Integrate[integrand, x, y];
anti2 = Integrate[integrand, y, x];
Simplify[anti1 - anti2]

(* Out: 2x^3/9 *)
```

This is *not* a bug, as the mixed partials of both expressions are the same.

```
Simplify[D[anti1, x, y] - D[anti2, x, y]]

(* Out: 0 *)
```

More generally, there is no reason to expect that 
$$\iint f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \iint f(x,y) \, dy \, dx,$$
as there is a choice of an arbitrary constant for the first integral.  As a very simple example, 
$$\int 0 \, dx = 1 \mbox{ and } \int 0 \, dx = y^2$$
are both reasonable choices for an integral with respect to $x$, assuming that the integrand is implicitly a function of $x$ and $y$.  The next integral with respect to $y$ then depends on which choice was made.

What *is* true is that (under reasonable assumptions on $f$),
$$\int_0^X \int_0^Y f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \int_0^Y \int_0^X f(x,y) \, dy \, dx.$$
This is called Fubini's theorem.

Thus,

```
anti3 = Integrate[integrand, {x, 0, X}, {y, 0, Y},
  Assumptions -> {X > 0, Y > 0}];
anti4 = Integrate[integrand, {y, 0, Y}, {x, 0, X},
 Assumptions -> {X > 0, Y > 0}];
Simplify[Simplify[anti3 - anti4] /. 
  ArcTan[Y/X] -> Pi/2 - ArcTan[X/Y]]

(* Out: 0 *)
```

Note that the `ArcTan[Y/X] -> Pi/2 - ArcTan[X/Y]` is a simplification that didn't happen automatically.

Comment: Got it thanks. I should have checked that http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+d%2Fdy+%5Bintegral++%5B%28xy+%28x%5E2+-+y%5E2%29%29%2F%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%29%5D+dy+dx%5D and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+d%2Fdy+%5Bintegral++%5B%28xy+%28x%5E2+-+y%5E2%29%29%2F%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%29%5D+dx+dy%5D give the same answer.